# Search for interactions between two users

Tags: feature-request, search, users

How can I search for all questions that involve participation by two particular users?

For example, I want to search for all of a particular user's questions that I have answered.

I'm not sure whether I'm asking to find direct interactions or indirect interactions.
In other words, if the two users left two answers to the same question, or commented on two different answers to the same question, but didn't interact directly, I'm not sure if I want that to count.

**EDIT**: With the new Lucene search, this *still* doesn't work!

Comment: I'd expect a search string of `+user:1234 +user:5678` (where numbers are user ID's), but this yields just the [search help page](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Buser%3A34397+%2Buser%3A157882).

Answer (score 10):

Here's [another](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/499/have-we-met), slightly more elaborate SEDE query. Sorry I didn't see your question sooner!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fairly simple [SEDE query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/438/interactions-between-users) to do the particular example you asked for, but it would definitely be useful to have search options to do that sort of thing more generally