# Can I query to see where a different user has crossed my path on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search for interactions between two users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60587/search-for-interactions-between-two-users)

While looking over the ongoing moderator election, it occurred to me that I'd love to see if any of the nominees ever answered or commented on my questions. Is there some way to query and see where another user's activity on Stack Overflow intersects my own?

Comment: You can use the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) for this, I think it includes all the relevant data.  It doesn't include votes, of course :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made this saved query: [Who Has Answered My Questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2100/who-has-answered-my-questions)

Comment: That looks very interesting, but I'm not sure how to interpret it. I put in my own userid, and got a list of people back. Is that everyone who has ever answered or commented on one of my posts? So in my moderator scenario, I'd take a particular moderator and see if they showed up on the list?

Comment: After playing around with the links in the results, I'm pretty sure my guess about the results is right - it is a list of everyone who answered one of my posts, with a link to the answer.

Comment: Bruce; right, you got it! I'd have joined on the list of mod candidates if there was such a list easily available.