# How can I check if a specific user has answered any of my questions?

Tags: support, search, data-explorer

Is there a way to check a specific user has answered a question of mine or not?

If the user did answer some of my questions, how can I get the list of those questions with the answers' links?

Currently, there is no such option available in the current [Search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=) functionality. Is that achievable via [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)?

For example: Recently, [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) reached a million reputation on Stack Overflow and I just want to check whether he answered any of my questions, but I didn't find any option to get the result.

Comment: Cross site duplicate: [How to make a query to see who answered who?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341202/4751173)

Comment: This answer has a query collecting also various other interactions: [How deep can the dive into user's interaction data be?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179427#179432) Here are also some other similar queries: [Is it possible to search for posts/questions of an user X commented on/answered by the user Y?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3266) (MathOverflow Meta)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The request can be done via Stack Exchange Data Explorer.
Below is the query to fetch the expected result:

```
SELECT Q.Id AS [Post Link], CONCAT('site://a/', A.Id, '|', A.Id) AS [Answer Link]
FROM Posts Q
JOIN Posts A ON A.ParentId = Q.Id AND A.PostTypeId = 2 AND A.OwnerUserId = @AnswererId
WHERE Q.PostTypeId = 1 AND Q.OwnerUserId = @OpId;
```

Query in SEDE with actual execution: [How to check if a specific user answered my question?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1342097/how-to-check-if-a-specific-user-answered-my-question)

Passing the original post and answerer's user id as the parameter will return the Post and answer link.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: output]