# Is there a method to see a graph of direct or indirect history with other specific users?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

In the last few weeks I've practiced frequent StackExchange activities, and it's enjoyable, rewarding, and above all, educational for me.

But I'm finding, the more I use the system, I've had repeated comment-exchanges and watched  others' answers, with the same users.  And I'm getting a sense for some individual users, people who have insight into topics I've liked to read.  Others, I've found are asking more-or-less for repeated "do my homework" type questions. Plus I've spotted some patterns of voting.

I'd like to know if there's a function somewhere on the site that provides a filtering of interactions with other users.

There are lots of places in the SE web interface that I'm still exploring, and may have missed such a feature if it exists.  The Inbox is great but only filters by question.

Also, a related but slightly distinct point would be, if I could associate my own private notes with particular questions/answers/users, to give me a context of past interaction on the fly.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60587/search-for-interactions-between-two-users

Comment: this would be an interesting bit of analysis to try on [the data dump](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump).